# Lock app to current screen orientation on launch

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an app where I don't want to manage `savedInstances` on orientation change, it sounds lazy but it's a such a pain in the ass for a beginner like me, maybe after learning a few tricks then I can implement it into the app.

Nonetheless, I want to support both landscape and portrait but in a different way. What I would like to do is detect the current screen orientation at the time the app was launched and  then lock the app session to that orientation. The application will then have to restart to force a change in screen orientation. If a change in orientation is detected, I would simply pop up a dialog box for 5 seconds to request for the application to relaunch.

This may not be the best way to go about it but I want to do it and I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can give you the code to lock orientation but I do not get what you mean by the dialog part. An orientation change essentially results in a relaunch, not of application, but of the Activity.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks. The dialog part is no problem, I should be able to do that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Add following property in activity tag in  manifest file

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: and what am I suppose to do inside the `onConfigurationChanged` to prevent orientation change?

Comment: use setContentView() in onConfigurationChanged.

Comment: First, this does not prevent orientation change, second it is commonly misused (in my opinion) to avoid handling orientation changes and can have some severe implications. For example views not being redrawn, scaled, handling different layouts for tablet at portrait/landscape later on etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

Class to handle lock/release of orientation:

```
public class Orientation {

    public static void lockOrientation(Activity activity) {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        int tempOrientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        int orientation = 0;
        switch (tempOrientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                    || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            else
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                    || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            else
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public static void releaseOrientation(Activity activity) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }

}
```

Then simply in onCreate of your Activity call `Orientation.lockOrientation(this)`

Comment: this worked well enough until i locked, unlocked the screen and changed orientation in between.

Comment: what device are you testing on? Sounds like the activity is destroyed in between or atleast that onCreate is called again.

Comment: Try setting android:launchMode="singleTask" on the Activity in manifest

Comment: But by the way - if the user lock the screen you risk losing the state, whether orientation changed or not.